# PHPUnit tests and Doctrine, too many connections

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, doctrine

I'm facing problems with "too many connections" for PHPUnit tests for ZF3 and Doctrine, because I'm executing ~200 tests per PHPUnit execution.
I've already found some questions and answers on stack overflow but non of these work.

My setup:
ZF2/ZF3, Doctrine 2 and PHPUnit.

I have a base test class for all tests and the setUp and tearDown function look like this:

```
public function setUp()
{
    $this->setApplicationConfig(Bootstrap::getConfig());
    Bootstrap::loadAllFixtures();
    if (!static::$em) {
        echo "init em";
        static::$em = Bootstrap::getEntityManager();
    }
    parent::setUp();
    ....
}

public function tearDown()
{
    parent::tearDown();
    static::$em->flush();
    static::$em->clear();
    static::$em->getConnection()->close();
    $refl = new \ReflectionObject($this);
    foreach ($refl->getProperties() as $prop) {
        if (!$prop->isStatic() && 0 !== strpos($prop->getDeclaringClass()->getName(), 'PHPUnit_')) {
            $prop->setAccessible(true);
            $prop->setValue($this, null);
        }
    }
    gc_collect_cycles();
}

public static function (Bootstrap::)loadAllFixtures()
{
    static::$em->getConnection()->executeUpdate("SET foreign_key_checks = 0;");
    $loader = new Loader();
    foreach (self::$config['data-fixture'] as $fixtureDir) {
        $loader->loadFromDirectory($fixtureDir);
    }
    $purger = new ORMPurger(static::$em);
    $executor = new ORMExecutor(static::$em, $purger);
    $executor->execute($loader->getFixtures());
    $executor = null;
    $purger = null;
    static::$em->getConnection()->executeUpdate("SET foreign_key_checks = 1;");
    static::$em->flush();
    static::$em->clear();
}
```

I'm monitoring my local MySQL server with innotop and the number of connections is increasing.

Do you have any ideas what I'm missing?

Thank you,
Alexander

Update 14.02.2017:
I've changed functions to use `static::$em` and added `Bootstrap::loadAllFixtures` method.

If I add `static::$em->close()` to `tearDown` method, all following test fail with message like "EntityManager already closed". `echo "init em";` is only call once and shown for the first test.
Is there a possibility to check if my Application opens connections without closing them? My test cases are based on AbstractHttpControllerTestCase

Comment: Why don't you share the same connection for every test? Could use the `setUpBeforeClass()` function and setting `$this->em` to a static like: `static::$em`. Depending on how many tests are defined per class that should help.

Comment: @sebastianForsberg 's answer is probably the way to go, but then don't forget to $em->clear() after each test otherwise you might have unexpected results.

Comment: I've changed my tests to use static::$em, but it does not solve the problem. With each executed test, connection count is incremented by 1. Is there a way to check if the application does not close all connections?

Comment: Hi @AlexanderLampret. Meanwhile did you find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I came across this problem too. Following the advice in PHPUnit's documentation I had done the following:

```
final public function getConnection()
{
    if ($this->conn === null) {
        if (self::$pdo == null) {

            //We get the EM from dependency injection container
            $container = $this->getContainer();
            self::$pdo = $container->get('Doctrine.EntityManager')->getConnection()->getWrappedConnection();
        }
        $this->conn = $this->createDefaultDBConnection(self::$pdo, 'spark_api_docker');
    }

    return $this->conn;
}
```

While `self:$pdo` was being shared, the number of 'threads_connected', when I observed `show status like '%onn%';` on my database, crept up until it reached the limit.

I found two solutions to this:

---

**1) Close the connection after each test**

```
public function tearDown()
{
    parent::tearDown();

    //You'll probably need to get hold of our entity manager another way
    $this->getContainer()->get('Doctrine.EntityManager')->getConnection()->close();
}
```

importantly, do not set `self::$pdo` to `null`. I had seen this as a recommendation elsewhere, but there's no point setting it as a static property and then resetting it after each test.

This works my closing connections that are no longer needed. When a testcase is finished, unless you have closed the connection it will remain open until the script ends (i.e. PHPUnit finishes running your test). Since you're creating a new connection for each test case, the number of connections goes up.

---

**2) Run each test in a seperate PHP thread**

This is the sledgehammer approach. It will likely impact the speed of your tests to one degree or another. In your phpunit.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<phpunit
    ...
    processIsolation = "true"
    >
    ...
</phpunit>
```

---

Returning to PHPUnit's advice, storing the connection and PDO helps with not creating new connections for each *test* but does not help you when you have many *test cases*. Each test case gets instantianted in the same thread, and each will create a new connection.

Answer (score 0):

Your tearDown method looks like it should do the trick. I just do this and have never experienced this issue

```
protected function tearDown()
{
    parent::tearDown();

    $this->em->close();
    $this->em = null; 
}
```

What does Bootstrap::loadAllFixtures method do? Is there any db connection in there that might be being overlooked?

Comment: `static::$em->close()` will lead to errors on the following tests, as the "EntityManager is already closed". `Bootstrap::loadAllFixtures()` is now shown above. If I comment this function call, tests may fail but connection number still increases.